# adding image to eclipse web project

Tags: java, image, web, project

Well, this is embarrasing...I can't seem to be able to add a humble image to a java web project in eclipse. What I did was that I created a folder called images inside WebContent, and then tried adding it in two ways, directly pasting it and using add/file, and advanced, which basically asks for a route to the image insider the hard drive.

The HTML syntax is here:

```
<img border="0" src="WebContent/images/network.jpg"
     alt="Pulpit rock" width="304" height="228">
```

I tried it with and without WebContent. I am sure there's something I'm missing, but after a couple hours decided to get help.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Can you please let us know the issue you are facing? Are you not able to see the image?

Comment: Exactly, the image just doesn't show on the webpage. By the way thanks for the really quick response.

Comment: Even if it shows, it seems to be a reference to the image on the harddrive, not the image itself as an element on the webproject

Comment: I think you need to remove that "WebContent".

Comment: @PradeepSimha WebContent-Folder is important in an Dynamic Web Project, its a Eclipse-Standard.

Comment: Since OPs JSPs will be in WebContent right? So I don't think he needs that, all of my jsps are having just path like `images/foo.jpg` like that.

Comment: @PradeepSimha Oh in the link? Yes, WebContent needs to be deleted. But not the Folder "WebContent" inside of the eclipse-project. :D

Comment: @PeterRader, Yup I said same. BTW +1 for your correct answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should in general try to avoid absolute paths. Specifically I believe from a normal web project you should try something like:

```
<img border="0" src="images/network.jpg"
     alt="Pulpit rock" width="304" height="228">
```

Which works like a charm for me.

Comment: I used your syntax and the image is shown, but only if I use right click, new, file, advanced, link to file in the file system, and I was wondering if this will affect the project once I put it on domain.com, even though I put the images in the webproject inside the workspace.

Comment: I think will will distribute correctly - personally I use WAR files to distribute TOMCAT servlet applications and so don't know that much about the publication process in your case.

Comment: This is not work for me. Can you help me? I have a java web project, and I also use ecplise and tomcat. I have created a folder called images inside the WebContent, and a image called qrcode.jpg is inside. While I use <img src="images/qrcode.jpg" />, the picture is not shown ,instead, it shows "X"

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the image within the eclipse project structure for eclipse to package it and have it available on the webserver. Just having the image on your local file system doesn't work. To do this, drag and drop the file from your file system onto the eclipse project tree folder.