# Images inside WebContent are not shown in html page

Tags: html, image, web-content

I read [adding image to eclipse web project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385955/adding-image-to-eclipse-web-project/19386175#19386175) which should be the same problem as I do.

But the solution is not working for me.

I also have the same folder called images inside WebContent, and i have a jpg image inside it. And in the html web page, i use `<img src="images/qrcode.jpg" />` . The page does not show the image, I also tried, `<img src="/images/qrcode.jpg" />` `<img src="../images/qrcode.jpg" />` but they not work either.

Can any body help me with this?

PS: I use the below code to to go to my page(wodinow is the project name, the html is inside the folder of pages)

```
response.sendRedirect("/wodinow/pages/userhelp.html");
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

have you checked given extension is correct? may be JPEG, jpeg. If nothing is work post your folder structure.

Comment: No, it is jpg fomat, and i uploaded the structure,would you please help to review?

Comment: <img src="../images/qrcode.jpg" /> this should work. But dont know whats happening.